# MPAndroidChart line graph doesn't like my real data

Tags: kotlin, linechart, mpandroidchart

My data looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "6e10e9fc-2d1f-4c5c-a1c5-d94d99ec55db",
    "air_temperature": 25.7,
    "timestamp": "2023-05-12 15:00:00",
    "parent_edge_device_id": "57028175-8f52-4bdd-b470-ff7485cdb80a"
}
```

`air_temperature` would be the axis Y value and `timestamp` would be converted to a date, take it's time, then converted to a `Float` to be the axis X. My code looks like this:

```
val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
for(item in items){
    val date = formatter.parse(item.timestamp)!!
    val dateTimestamp = date.time

    val entry = Entry(
        dateTimestamp.toFloat(),
        item.air_temperature!!,
        ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(resources, R.drawable.ic_star, null)
    )
    values.add(entry)
}
```

I made an `Entry` that satisfies the class, but the library doesn't seem to like it and won't display it.

I also think I'm getting an error related to this that looks like this.

> java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -16     at
> com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer.generateTransformedValuesLine(Transformer.java:178)
> at
> com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LineChartRenderer.drawValues(LineChartRenderer.java:549)
> at
> com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarLineChartBase.onDraw(BarLineChartBase.java:278)
> at android.view.View.draw(View.java:22644)  at
> android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:21519)   at
> android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4512)

Which is quite confusing, because I'm sure something is getting inserted to the values `List`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error can happen if the data is not sorted by X value.

This is described in the [MPAndroidChart docs](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Setting-Data#the-order-of-entries) and this [Github issue](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/2074) too, along with a solution for how to sort the data.

> Please be aware that this library does not officially support drawing LineChart data from an Entry list not sorted by the x-position of the entries in ascending manner. Adding entries in an unsorted way may result in correct drawing, but may also lead to unexpected behaviour.

You can use the `EntryXComparator` provided in MPAndroidChart to easily sort them

```kotlin
val values = mutableListOf<Entry>()
// fill the values array
values.sortWith(EntryXComparator())
```

or just use a native Kotlin sort

```kotlin
values.sortBy { it.x }
```

Comment: Interesting, will try this out

Comment: Small question, the data works now, but it doesn't get displayed immediately, I have to tap the graph first for them to show up. The data is from a server, so I only set the data once the app receives them. What might be the cause of that behavior?

Comment: There isn't enough information to say why, maybe the data is loaded asynchronously but you don't call `chart.invalidate()` after setting new data?

Comment: No, I didn't. I don't think the examples have that. Just checked, `chart.invalidate()` was way below the parts that I thought was only relevant parts. Is `chart.invalidate()` a mandatory thing to do?

Comment: Without seeing your code i can only guess, but you usually need to call invalidate if you change the data after it's been drawn. If you're setting the data in a callback after getting server data, this is usually the case.